# Can't read SASS files with Hugo

Tags: sass, netlify, hugo, netlify-cms

Dear Excellent developes.

I'm trying to duild static web site with Hugo (Netlify CMS).
I wanna build from scratch, if I can;-) ( I designed the site by myself. SO I wanna write sass from scratch).

But, sass files aren't read successflly.
Do you solve the problem?

## I checked there pages to solve it , But I couldn't

- https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/scss-sass/
- https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/custom-css-throws-type-nil-not-supported-in-resource-transformations/19942

## the structure of this Web site

Basically, there are not many changes from Hugo install.

- layouts/index.html // I write there the following code.
- resources/_gen/assets/sass/main.scss // I wrote simple css to this file → html {background: yellow;}

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js"></script>
  {{ $sassTemplate := resources.Get "sass/main.scss"  }}
  {{ $style := $sassTemplate | resources.ExecuteAsTemplate "main.scss" . | resources.ToCSS }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ $style.relURL }}">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Nice. It's looking good already.</h1>
  <ul>
    {{ range (where .Pages "Section" "blog") }}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">
        {{ .Title }}
      </a>
    </li>
    {{ end }}
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

## Error messages

```
Rebuild failed:

Failed to render pages: render of "home" failed: "/Users/RPOISITORY-NAME/layouts/index.html:11:40": execute of template failed: template: index.html:11:40: executing "index.html" at <resources.ExecuteAsTemplate>: error calling ExecuteAsTemplate: type <nil> not supported in Resource transformations
↓
  <script src="https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js"></script>
  {{ $sassTemplate := resources.Get "sass/main.scss"  }}
  {{ $style := $sassTemplate | resources.ExecuteAsTemplate "main.scss" . | resources.ToCSS }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ $style.relURL }}">
</head>

hugo v0.81.0+extended darwin/amd64 BuildDate=unknown
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.scss` files must be in the `assets` folder **at the root of your project**, and not in the sub-folder `resources/_gen/assets`.

I wrote [a post in french on the topic](https://roneo.org/hugo-sass-theme-beautifullhugo/), maybe you can grab some hints / use a translator